# How to hide /show multiple right button in the Navigation Bar swift 5

Tags: swift

I need to hide the two right button in the Navigation Bar, then unhide it after the user selects some options.I added two buttons(i.e search and setting button) in the storyboard

Unfortunately, the following doesn't work:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.isHidden = true
```

if I use below code then not able to show them again

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
```

Answer (score 1):

Add them programatically

```
class YourVC: UIViewController {
    var item1 = UIBarButtonItem()
    var item2 = UIBarButtonItem()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let btn1 = UIButton()
        btn1.setImage(UIImage(named: "validImage1"), for: .normal)
        btn1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        item1.customView = btn1
        
        let btn2 = UIButton()
        btn2.setImage(UIImage(named: "validImage2"), for: .normal)
        btn2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
        item2.customView = btn2
        
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [item1,item2]
    }
}
```

You can hide them:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = nil
```

and show:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [item1,item2]
```

Comment: it doesn't work properly. while showing, only one button is visible.

Comment: Are you attached btn1 to item1, and btn2 to item2? I tested this code it worked properly